# Task<ActionResult> returns Square Brackets

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0

I have a Web Method, in my WebCore API 7.0 Restful application, that is returning square brackets in the JSON string:

```json
[
    {
        "employeeId": "ddavidson",
        "firstName": "David",
        "lastName": "Davidson",
        "companyName": "Some Random Company",
        "fWarehouseId": 1
    }
]
```

When I test it in Postman or through my application I get the above results with square brackets. **When I test it in Swagger I get what I expect, without the square brackets**. This is the Web Method call:

```
   [HttpGet("{id},{password}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<EmployeeInfo>> LoginEmployee(string id, string password)
    {
        if (_context.Employees == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        var employee = await _context.Employees.FindAsync(id);

        if (employee == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (!employee.Password.Equals(password))
        {
            return NoContent();
        }

        try
        {
            var jsonEmployee = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employee);
            EmployeeInfo? employeeInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmployeeInfo>(jsonEmployee.ToString());

            if (employeeInfo == null)
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);

            return employeeInfo;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError); ;
        }
    }
```

I am not returning an IEnumerable object, just the object itself. I do not want to have to remove the square brackets in the method call of my application, I would rather have the method respond correctly.

Here is EmployeeInfo class:

```
public class EmployeeInfo
{
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; } = null!;

    public string? FirstName { get; set; }

    public string? LastName { get; set; }

    public string? CompanyName { get; set; }

    public short? FWarehouseId { get; set; }
}
```

and the Employee Class:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; } = null!;

    public string Password { get; set; } = null!;

    public string? FirstName { get; set; }

    public string? LastName { get; set; }

    public string? CompanyName { get; set; }

    public short? FWarehouseId { get; set; }

    public bool? Active { get; set; }

    public virtual Warehouse? FWarehouse { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> FRoles { get; } = new List<Role>();
}
```

Comment: What is `EmployeeInfo`? Can you please add the type definition?

Comment: Square brackets denotes array/list/etc; any chance that `EmployeeInfo : IEnumerable<SomeOtherType>` or similar?

Comment: Sorry, added EmployeeInfo to the post.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand. The only thing left out is the namespace. The Employee class is an Entity Framework Scaffold. Do you need to see all the related classes to Employee?

Comment: I assume you meant ASP.NET Core Web API when you said "WebCore API 7.0", since AFAIK, there's no such thing as "WebCore". I added the appropriate tags; you may wish to [edit] the text.

Comment: Why are you serializing and immediately deserializing an object? That's a distinct code smell. (Also, `SerializeObject` returns a string, so there's no need for the `.ToString()` on the result of that call).

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the method when testing to exclude the possibility that your test uses an older binary or another method or another project altogether

Comment: Thanks @NineBerry. I did do that and it is doing it is using the correct method etc. I still don't know why it would return a json object in Swagger correctly but not in Postman (or in my project).

Comment: Thank you @NineBerry, I believe I found an issue based off your comment. I am working with one record in the database so went and added two records; well I got back two records. I will return with the answer when I find out exactly what is happening. Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I serialized and desterilized it into another object for testing purposes. I though the collection of the Employee class may be adding the brackets so I wanted to serialize it into an object that had none. I think my url in calling it may be incorrect, while the one in Swagger is the correct url. Thank you for your advice on SerializeObject.

Comment: @MrRob just change the return type to `Task<EmployeeInfo>`

Answer (score 0):

I was making the call in my code (and in postman) incorrectly. Swagger was doing it correctly. I did as NineBerry suggested but instead of stepping through it during runtime I published it and attached the Web Service Process, ran my client application and noticed when I called the API it went for the web method that returns all employees, not the one that should return only one employee. Thanks again NineBerry and to everyone else that helped.

Comment: Well yeah, that was what I meant: Debug the code in the actual usage scenario where the bug happens. As a tip: Invest some minutes to setup your development environment so that you can debug the server code and client code together in one debugging session without having to manually attach to processes. This is usually very simple with Visual Studio.